# How to login to discord account using Invoke-webrequest?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Problem: I have tried searching the internet for solutions but none seems to work. This is mainly because when you do this: `(Invoke-Webrequest -Uri www.discord.com/login).Forms`, it turns up empty. There is no form to fill in, so I cannot login.

What I have tried:

1.

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$login = Invoke-WebRequest discord.com/login -SessionVariable ds
$login.Forms[0].Fields.email = $Cred.Username
$login.Forms[0].Fields.pass = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

2. 

```
$fLogin = @{
email = "email@email.net"
password = "password"
}

$login = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://discord.com/login' -SessionVariable "sv" -Form $fLogin -Method Post
```

Comment: Any particular reason you want to emulate a user in a browser? It'd probably be much easier to do whatever you want to do via [Discord's APIs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I wanted to make an app that could download images sent in a discord channel without requiring to be invited into said server first.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're logging in, I'm assuming you're trying to make a bot?

## API verse Browser

You'll want to use the [Web API](https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro) instead of automating UI interactions. The first will be more reliable, more robust to changes, and use less resources.

## Types of bots:

1. A `WebHook` or
2. An actual bot

If you use a `WebHook` you don't need a bot account, and the [Authentication is easier to get started with because it's not OAuth2](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#authentication)

## Setup

In Settings go to: `Server Settings -> Integrations -> View Webhooks`, and create your webhook.

[image: webhook creation]

## Post Messages using `Invoke-RestMethod`

Use `Invoke-RestMethod` for Web Api's. It simplifies things.

```
$webhookUri = 'https://discord.com/api/YourWebhookUrlHere'

$Body = @{
  'username' = 'Nomad'
  'content' = 'https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Nomad'
}
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $webhookUri -Method 'post' -Body $Body
```

## Output

[image]

- Docs [Discord API: WebHooks](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook)
- (There's slightly more details on my Page [ninmonkeys.com/blog/2021/01/22/creating-a-discord-webhook-in-a-few-lines-of-powershell/](https://ninmonkeys.com/blog/2021/01/22/creating-a-discord-webhook-in-a-few-lines-of-powershell/) )

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am trying to make an app that downloads images in a discord channel. However, using either webhooks or bot account would require me to have permission to invite the bot into the server(requires manage server permission i think). I want my app to be able to operate without being inside the server.  Friend wants to login into the his own account and download all images in a specified server and channel.

Comment: I am exploring the possibility of using start "website.com" but it don't seem to hold any promise.

Comment: That will just invoke the url in your default browser. You'll look at the api <https://discord.com/developers/doc> to find the endpoints you want. If you want to authenticate with a bot you need to register a token with your app. see OAuth2 https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#oauth2